# Magento 2 RequireJs callback not called

Tags: magento2, jquery, requirejs

I have the following in requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "jquery/easing": "./js/jquery.easing.1.3",
            "jquery/mobile/customized": "./js/jquery.mobile.customized.min",
            "camera": "./js/camera.min"
        }
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery/easing": ['jquery'],
        "jquery/mobile/customized": ['jquery'],
        "camera": ['jquery', 'jquery/easing', 'jquery/mobile/customized']
        }
    }
};
```

And the following code in a Block:

```
require(['jquery', 'jquery/easing', 'jquery/mobile/customized', 'camera'], function(jQuery) {
    console.log('test');
});
```

The js files are loaded, but the callback function never gets called.
Do I need to do further modifications to the js files to be compatible with RequireJs?

Comment: did you try by enabling magento developer mode ? if not run this command on your magento root `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

Comment: I just tried with developer mode on and it's the same. I get no js errors, and the callback function never gets called.